# Plot points colored in a gradient based on a range provided by a column in the original dataset within a PCA plot in R

Tags: r, plot, pca

I am using fviz_pca_ind() to plot observations after a pca analysis.

I would like to plot a subsample of my observations based on a given column in the original dataset in a gradient. And the rest of the data in gray circles.

Let say I would like to color the points based on Rsq for groups 1-4, knowing that Group 5 does not have that value but I still want to see group 5 in the background in gray.

```
iris_mod <- iris %>% mutate(Group = sample(1:5, 150, replace = TRUE))
iris_mod <- iris_mod %>% mutate(Rsq = case_when(Group == 1 ~ 0.05, 
                                                Group == 2 ~ 0.5, 
                                                Group == 3 ~ 0.65, 
                                                Group == 4 ~ 0.75, 
                                                Group == 5 ~ NA))

iris.pca <- prcomp(iris_mod[,1:4], scale. = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to add your points manually using a `geom_point()` where you add the additional column(s) from your original data using e.g. `dplyr::bind_cols`. As doing might overplot some of the labels I would also suggest to add the labels manually. Additionally I removed the layers added by `fviz_pca_ind` by setting `geom= "blank"`. Finally, you could set your desired "grey" color via the `na.value´ argument of e.g.` scale_color_gradient`:

```
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(factoextra)

fviz_pca_ind(iris.pca, geom = "blank") +
  geom_point(data = ~ bind_cols(.x, iris_mod[-c(1:4)]), aes(color = Rsq)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = name),
    hjust = .5, vjust = 0, label.size = 0, fill = NA,
    label.padding = unit(6, "pt")
  ) +
  scale_color_gradient(na.value = "grey80")
```

[image]

Comment: it worked like a charm! Thank you so much! So, basically you can nullify the parameters within the fviz_pca_ind() function and add other geoms like if it was a ggplot?